# Hopcroft's algorithm - DFA Minimization

Tags: java, algorithm, computation-theory

I want to implement Hopcroft's algorithm to minimize a DFA [WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization). Until now I can remove unreachable states. The problem is that I don't understand this algorithm. I don't know how to implement it. Can somebody explain it? Or maybe expand on the algorithm so that its more understandable to implement. I don't get the following part of the algorithm at all:

```
 let X be the set of states for which a transition on c leads to a state in A
      for each set Y in P for which X ∩ Y is nonempty and Y \ X is nonempty do
           replace Y in P by the two sets X ∩ Y and Y \ X
```

The algorithm is as following:

[image]

what I have implemented so far(poorly written, will do clean up once i finish it):

```
    package dRegAut;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class dfamin {

    // Global variables to hold data from the file
    private int numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates;
    private char alphabets[];
    private int finalStates[];
    private int [][] transitionTable;



    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws NumberFormatException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        int numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates;
        char alphabets[];
        int finalStates[];
        int [][] transitionTable;

        /*
         * INPUT FILE FORMAT: numberOfStates numberofAlphabets transitions1 transtions2 ... numberOfFianlStates FinalState(s)
         * Example: 
         *          8 2 1 5 6 2 0 2 2 6 7 5 2 6 6 4 6 2 2 2 6
         *          5 2 0 1 0 1 3 4 3 4 2 4 3 0 2 3
         *          8 2 1 0 0 2 3 1 3 0 3 5 6 4 5 6 6 3 1 3
         *          9 2 1 4 2 5 3 7 4 7 5 8 6 1 7 1 8 2 0 4 3 2 5 8
         */

        // Take file name and open a stream to read it
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream));

        // Store each line from the file
        String line;

        // Read each line from file
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            // Read single spaced data from each line
            String [] splittedLine = line.split(" ");

            // Read numStates,numAlphabets from the line
            numStates = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[0]);
            numAlphabets = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[1]);
            //for(int a=0;a<numAlphabets;a++){
                //alphabets[a] = '0';
            //}
            transitionTable = new int[numStates][numAlphabets];
            int tt= 2;
            // Loop thorough the line and read transition table
            for(int row=0;row<numStates;row++){

                for(int col=0;col<numAlphabets;col++){
                    transitionTable[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[tt]);

                    tt++;

                }// End of for-loop to go thorough alphabets
            }// End of for-loop to go thorough states

            // Read number of final states
            numFinalStates = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[2+numStates*numAlphabets]);
            //System.out.println(numFinalStates);
            // Read final states
            int z=0;
            finalStates = new int[numFinalStates];
            int start = 3+numStates*numAlphabets ;
            int end = (3+(numStates*numAlphabets))+numFinalStates;
            for(int fs=start;fs<end;fs++){
                finalStates[z] = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[fs]);
                //System.out.println(finalStates[z]);
                z++;
            }// End of for-loop to read all final states
            dfamin x = new dfamin(numStates,numAlphabets,numFinalStates,finalStates,transitionTable);
            x.minimizer();
            System.out.println(x);



        }// End of while-loop to read file

        // Close the stream
        br.close();

    }

    dfamin(int nS,int nA,int nFS,int fS[], int [][] tT){
        numStates = nS;
        numAlphabets = nA;
        numFinalStates = nFS;
        //alphabets = a;
        finalStates = fS;
        transitionTable = tT;

    }// End of DFAMinimizer constructor

    /*
     * A method to minmize the dfa  
     */

    public void minimizer(){

        // Remove unreachable States
        ArrayList<Integer> reachableStates = reachableStates(numStates, numAlphabets,transitionTable);

        // Store all final states
        ArrayList<Integer> fStates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Loop thorugh finalStates array and transfer its data to array list
        for(int fs:finalStates){
            fStates.add(fs);
        }// End of for-loop

        // Store all non final states
        ArrayList<Integer> nonFStates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Store only non final states in nonFstates
        nonFStates = nonFinalStates(reachableStates,fStates);

        //TODO: IMPLEMENT HOPCROFT's ALGORITHM


    }// End of minimizer method

    /*
     * unreachableStates - A method to find unreachable states of a DFA 
     * 
     */
    public ArrayList<Integer> reachableStates(int numStates, int numAlphabets, int [][] transitionTable){

        // Initialize a list to hold temporary list of states in it
        ArrayList<Integer> reachableStates =new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> newStates = new ArrayList();


        // Start from the state zero
        reachableStates.add(0);
        newStates.add(0);
        // Temporary array to hold reachable states
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList();
        // Loop until there is data in newStates
        do{
            // Empty temp array
            temp.clear();
            // Loop thorough all the states, and check for {p such that p=δ(q,c)};
            for(int j=0;j<newStates.size();j++){

                for(int i=0; i<numAlphabets;i++){
                    // If found add it to the temp set
                    temp.add(transitionTable[newStates.get(j)][i]);

                } // End of for-loop to go thorough all characters

            }// End of for-loop to go thorough all elements of the newStates array list

            // Clear newStates list
            newStates.clear();

            // Add the elements that are in temp, but are not in reachableStates to newStates
            // new_states := temp \ reachable_states;
            for(int z=0;z<temp.size();z++){

                for(int z1=0; z1<reachableStates.size();z1++){


                    // If the state was already present, don't add
                    if(temp.get(z) == reachableStates.get(z1)){
                        break;
                    }
                    if(temp.get(z) != reachableStates.get(z1) && z1 == reachableStates.size()-1){
                        // Only from temp to newstates if its not in reachablestates currently
                        newStates.add(temp.get(z));

                    }


                }// End of for-loop to go thorough all reachableStates elements and check if a match
            }// End of for-loop thorugh all temp states

            // If newStates list is not empty then add it to the reachableStates
            if(!newStates.isEmpty()){
                // Add the newStates elements to reachable states
                for(int y=0;y<newStates.size();y++){
                    //System.out.printf("newStates:%d newStatesSize:%d in %d",newStates.get(y),newStates.size(),y);
                    reachableStates.add(newStates.get(y));
                }
            }

        }while(!newStates.isEmpty());

        reachableStates = removeDuplicate(reachableStates);

        return reachableStates;

    }// End of unreachableStates method

    /*
     * removeDuplicate - a function to remove duplicate entries from an ArrayList
     * 
     */
    ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicate(ArrayList<Integer> input){

        // Remove duplicate entries from reachableStates list
        // Compare the first index, with all other indexes, compare the second with all other indexes
        for(int i=0;i<input.size()-1;i++){

            for(int j=i+1;j<input.size();j++){
                // If dupblicate states remove it
                if(input.get(i) == input.get(j)){
                    input.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }// End of for-loop to remove duplicate entries from reachableList

        // Sort the list before returning
        Collections.sort(input);
        // Return the list
        return input;
    }// End of removeDuplicate method


    /*
     * nonFinalStates - a method to return an array list of nonfinal states, given all and final states
     * 
     */
    ArrayList<Integer> nonFinalStates(ArrayList<Integer> allStates, ArrayList<Integer> finalStates){
        // All non final States
        ArrayList<Integer> nonFinalStates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Loop thorough allStates, and compare each state with the list of finalstates
        for(int i=0; i<allStates.size();i++){
            // Loop thorough list of final states
            for(int j=0; j<finalStates.size();j++){
                // If a state is final state
                if(allStates.get(i) == finalStates.get(j)){
                    // Then remove it from the list
                    allStates.remove(i);
                }
            }// End of for-loop to travers finalstates
        }// End of for-loop to traverse allstates

        return nonFinalStates;

    }



    // returns a string that is compatible with our input file specification
    public String toString()    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        //buf.append(" "+ numStates +" ");
        //buf.append ( numAlphabets + " " );
        buf.append("Transition Table: ");
        for ( int i = 0; i < numStates; i++ )   {
            for ( int j = 0; j < numAlphabets; j++ )    {
                buf.append ( " "+ transitionTable[i][j] + " " );
            }
        }

        buf.append ( "Number of Final State(s): "+numFinalStates + " Final State(s): " );
        for ( int i = 0; i < numFinalStates; i++ )

                buf.append ( finalStates[i] + " " );
        return buf.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to explain the algorithm in an intuitive way without drawing out the DFA and walking through it on a whiteboard. In terms of implementing it, it is best (in my experience) to put the pseudocode in as comments, and write code to implement each piece. For this particular algorithm, it helps a great deal to use an actual math-style Set class (with support for things like union and intersect, etc) so that you can implement things verbatim (note that's not necessarily the most efficient way, but it lets you translate the pseudocode much easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call two DFA states *equivalent* if it's impossible to tell from accepting/rejecting behavior alone which of them the DFA is in. For each language, the minimum DFA accepting that language has no equivalent states.

Hopcroft's algorithm for DFA minimization works by computing the equivalence classes of the states of the unminimized DFA. The nub of this computation is an iteration where, at each step, we have a partition of the states that is coarser than equivalence (i.e., equivalent states always belong to the same set of the partition).

1. The initial partition is accepting states and rejecting states. Clearly these are not equivalent.
2. Suppose that we have states q1 and q2 in the same set of the current partition. Letting the transition function be delta, if there exists a symbol sigma such that delta(q1, sigma) and delta(q2, sigma) are in different sets of the partition, then we know by the coarseness invariant that these states are not equivalent, i.e., there exists a string x such that delta(delta(q1, sigma), x) and delta(delta(q2, sigma), x) differ in whether they accept/reject. But delta(delta(q1, sigma), x) = delta(q1, sigma x), so the string sigma x differentiates between q1 and q2. The logic that you've quoted is to split one of the partition sets appropriately.
3. The interesting part of the proof of correctness is that, when Step 2 is not possible, we have arrived at the true equivalence classes.

The pseudocode looks more complicated than this because it's concerned with the efficiency with which we can find applications of Step 2.

Comment: Thank you. I am implementing my code using this logic, hopefully it would be correct!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the example given in the original paper may help visualize this algorithm.

http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/71/190/CS-TR-71-190.pdf

> We illustrate the algorithm by an example before specifying it in
>   detail.Extensive use of list processing is employed to reduce the
>   computation time.